# in java to test if the brackets in a formula is matching, is my algorithm right?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, brackets

Here is my analysis to this problem: There are four kinds of conditions where the brackets is matching: `{{()}}`, `{}[]<>`, `<{}[]>`, `{<>[]}<>`
So it could be complicated if I just think about these 4 matching forms. So I try to find out when is the brackets is not matching. if I let `{` and `}` be a pair, I find out if one bracket is on the odd position then his pair must be in a even position, vice versa. Take `{<>[]}<>` as an example, `{` is at the 1st position which is an odd position and `}` is at the 6th position which is an even position. Therefore I use numbers to mark them which `'()'--1,9; '[]'--2,8; '<>' --3,7; '{}' --4,6` so if two number adds up is equals to 10 then these two numbers represents a pair. Then I use those numbers to represent bracket structure. and I pull out bracket in odd position and bracket in even position(use number to represent them) and I add each items in odd position and even position with each other to see if there is a match which adds up is 10, if not, I say it's a match. My code is as below:

```
/** Matching Brackets
  * Tony
  */
import java.util.*;

public class Solution19 {

  public static String process(String n) {
    /** build a condition combination: */
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
      if (n.charAt(i) == '(' || n.charAt(i) == ')' || n.charAt(i) == '[' || n.charAt(i) == ']' 
            || n.charAt(i) == '<' || n.charAt(i) == '>' || n.charAt(i) == '{' || n.charAt(i) == '}') {
        newString += n.charAt(i);
      }
    }
    return newString;
  }


  public static String numForm(String s) {
    String newone = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      switch(s.charAt(i)) {
        case '(': newone += "1 ";break;
        case ')': newone += "9 ";break;
        case '[': newone += "2 ";break;
        case ']': newone += "8 ";break;
        case '<': newone += "3 ";break;
        case '>': newone += "7 ";break;
        case '{': newone += "4 ";break;
        case '}': newone += "6 ";break;
      }
    }
    return newone;
  }

  public static int[] intArray(String m) {
    String[] stringArray = m.split(" ");
    int[] intArr = new int[stringArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
      intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
    }
    return intArr;
  }

  public static void printArray (int[] array) {
    for (int n : array) {
      System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
  }

  public static int[] oddPosition (int[] array) {
    int [] oddNumbers = new int[array.length / 2];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0) {
        oddNumbers[j] = array[i];
        j ++;
      }
    }
    return oddNumbers;
  }

  public static int[] evenPosition (int[] array) {
    int [] evenNumbers = new int[array.length / 2];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        evenNumbers[j] = array[i];
        j ++;
      }
    }
    return evenNumbers;
  }

  public static boolean addsUpten (int [] array) {
    boolean conditionSum = false;
    boolean conditionSingle = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      int d = 0;
      while (i + d < array.length) {
        if (array[i] + array[i+d] == 10) {
          conditionSingle = true;
        }
        conditionSum = (conditionSum || conditionSingle);
        d ++;
      }
    }
    return conditionSum;
  }




  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int times = sc.nextInt();
    String voider = sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < times; i ++) {
      String formula = sc.nextLine();
      String processed = process(formula);

      String numFormed = numForm(processed);
      // System.out.println(numFormed);
      int[] numArray = intArray(numFormed);

      if (numArray.length % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.print("0 ");
      }
      else {
        int[] oddNumbers = oddPosition(numArray);

        int[] evenNumbers = evenPosition(numArray);


        if (addsUpten(oddNumbers) || addsUpten(evenNumbers) == true) {
          System.out.print("0 ");
        }
        else {
          System.out.print("1 ");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as I expected, it should work and it does work when I input:

```
4
(a+[b*c]-{d/3})
(a + [b * c) - 17]
(((a * x) + [b] * y) + c
auf(zlo)men [gy<psy>] four{s}
```

it gives me output:`1 0 0 1` (1 represent it is a match, 0 represent it's not a match). However when I input something longer like `[^]<t>(z){<[^]<w>[{f}c]y[-][v]{<y>g<+( )>(c){w{a{t}}}}>((a)w)}` it is a match but it gives me 0. I wonder the way I determine if it's a match or not is right or wrong? What did I miss? Sorry for the long code, just wondering `("I find out if one bracket is on the odd position then his pair must be in a even position, vice versa.")` this way to describe a bracket match is right or wrong? Thx!

Comment: Your even/odd assumption is obviously wrong. Just take the example `(a)`.

Comment: "(a)" will first transformed into "()";    '(' is 1st,  ')' is 2nd. so one is odd another is even. What's wrong?

Comment: Avoid `String +=` in Java loops - use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). I think your condition to be not only overly complicated, but just necessary, not sufficient.

Comment: @greybeard Thx I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach has a fundamental problem - it does not support nesting very well.

You can solve this by creating a stack of parentheses:

- When you see an opening parenthesis, you push it on the stack
- When you see a closing parenthesis, you pop an opening parenthesis that is supposed to pair with it off the stack
- If the pair from the stack matches, continue
- If the pair does not match, or the stack is empty, report a mismatch
- If the stack is not empty at the end of the loop, also report a mismatch.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for offering a very useful approach! Could you tell me why my approach does not support nesting very well?

Comment: @TonyChen Because the oddness/evenness of open and closed positions can be changed by nesting an odd number of open brackets that would be balanced later, e.g. `{<<()>>}` [causes your program to print zero](http://ideone.com/o7vR84).

Comment: Oh I see! that's it! Thank you!